# ubercart invoice generation to allow user to request funds withdrawal

Tags: 6, ubercart, commerce

I have a site where user purchases some service and once the service is received by the purchased person, i should allow the service provider to raise a invoice order to request funds.

what are the modules that i should use to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing the "service" as part of your site, you can attach the "services" to the user by assigning permissions to the "service" to a role, then create a content type, enable it as product and attach a "feature" to a product to enable the role for a limited amount of time (if this is your business model).

This would use CCK (to define the product) + Ubercart (for setting up the shop and attaching Product + feature to product) as well as Permissions (to your "service") and Roles (to apply to the permissions).

I hope this has been of some help!